# Integral divided in equal parts?

Tags: integration

Assuming $f$ is locally integrable on on interval $(a,b)$, I'd like to show that it is always possible to divide it into two equal parts in terms of enclosed areas.

In other words, I'd like to show there exists $x\in[a,b]$ where

$$\int_a^xf(x)dx=\int_x^bf(x)dx$$

I got stuck composing a helper function $h(x)=\int_a^xf(x)dx-\int_x^bf(x)dx.$  I thought it might be useful, but I don't really know how I could apply the mean value theorem to show that it is possible to find an $x$ such that $h(x)=0$.

P.S.:  Also, I think it only works on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xsSE8.png

Comment: Edited so that the question shows on the site, instead of an image.

Comment: For a continuous function $f$ (but we can do with less), $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is continuous, so Intermediate Value Theorem. What integral are you asking about? Riemann? Lebesgue with the usual measure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the existence of a primitive function $\;F(x)\;$  of $\;f(x)\;$ in $\;[a,b]\;$, i.e.:

$$\;F'(x)=f(x)\;\;\forall\,x\in[a,b]\;$$ we get:

$$\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx= F(b)-F(a)$$

Now

$$\int\limits_a^xf(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(a)\;,\;\;\int\limits_x^bf(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(x)$$

and you want

$$F(x)-F(a)=F(b)-F(x)\iff F(x)=\frac12\left(F(a)+F(b)\right)$$

And this can always be solved.

Yet there are very naughty functions which can be integrable in some interval yet they have no primitive there, and thus the above cannot be applied...